# select into outfile not working with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to execute de following code in Hibernate to create a .csv file from a mySQL database. :

```
String sql = 
"SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'table.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','" +
" OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' " +
"FROM match INNER JOIN totala ON match_code= match";
```

The .csv file is created correctly but then I get the following error:

```
Exception monitoring the input folder org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2452)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2192)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2187)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1832)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:179)
    at com.salebuild.dao.hibernate.CorporateTitleDAOImpl.dumpTitleCompanyCSV(CorporateTitleDAOImpl.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
    at $Proxy128.dumpTitleCompanyCSV(Unknown Source)
    at com.salebuild.service.CorporateTitleServiceImpl.dumpTitleCompanyCSV(CorporateTitleServiceImpl.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy159.dumpTitleCompanyCSV(Unknown Source)
    at com.salebuild.service.collector.ContactScraperMonitorInputFolder.addNewFile(ContactScraperMonitorInputFolder.java:61)
    at com.salebuild.service.collector.ContactScraperMonitorInputFolder.run(ContactScraperMonitorInputFolder.java:37)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:7021)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.next(NewProxyResultSet.java:2859)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:741)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449)
    ... 29 more
```

Some googling suggested that it may be because query is not returning any result so I get "java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data". But how do I get over this exception.I dont want my code to break.

I am running the query like:

```
public void dumpTitleCompanyCSV(String titleId,String titleName, String dumpFolder) {
        Session session = getSession();
        String hql = "SELECT "+titleId+" ,id, \""+titleName+"\", name " +
                    "FROM company INTO OUTFILE 'd:/contact/input/file.csv' " +
                    "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'";
        logger.debug("jeets The query is \n "+hql);
        Query query  = session.createSQLQuery(hql);
         query.list();
    }
```

Comment: How are you running this query?

Comment: @Thihara,i have updated my post and appended the code i am using to run the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `executeUpdate()` method to run queries that doesn't return any results.

In your case since the results will be dumped to a external file there will be no result set. Note that this is different than a query that may return empty results due to the criteria not being met.

EDIT :

Since that also seem to be failing I think you may need to try using pure JDBC.

Do something like below

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        //run your query natively here
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried even that.It doesn't work gives exception "Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue executeUpdate() for SELECTs"