# Executing INTO OUTFILE in Hibernate.ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am new to hibernate.This is my code.

```
String sql = "SELECT EVENT_ID,EVENT_DATE,EVENT_TITLE  FROM EVENTS WHERE EVENT_TITLE='My First Event' INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/report.csv'    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);

query.list();
```

The file is generated at the path "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/".

But i get an exception.

ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
I understand that there is no resultset returned from the query.But is there any way to solve this.Pls help.

The csv file is generated.i just have to get rid of the exception somehow.
OR is there any other way to execute such commands.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select into outfile not working with hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715841/select-into-outfile-not-working-with-hibernate)

Comment: You probably need to use plain JDBC and [`Statement.execute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)) for this. Spooling data into a CSV file server-side is something you shouldn't be doing with an ORM in the first place.

Comment: or execute it in a STORED PROCEDURE and return a dummy ROW like - select 1,2,3,4;